# Crashing on UITableViewReorderingSupport in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am getting this exception [_UITableViewReorderingSupport setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x70f9780

I am using custom cells for table view
can anybody tell me the possibilities why this happening????

```
if (cell == nil) { 
  cell = [[CCUnbilledTransactionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier_3]; 
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCUnbilledTransactionCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
  cell = objCCUnbilledTransactionCell; 
  self.objCCUnbilledTransactionCell=nil; 
}
```

Comment: if (cell == nil) 
{ 
cell = [[CCUnbilledTransactionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier_3]; 
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCUnbilledTransactionCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
cell = objCCUnbilledTransactionCell; 
self.objCCUnbilledTransactionCell=nil; 

}

Answer (score 0):

This crash is appearing since your cell is not of UITableViewCell type. You can check your object type while you debug, if that is the case you can do it as follows.

Try to check your object type as below:

```
 cell = [[CCUnbilledTransactionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] ;
        NSArray *toplavelobject=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CCUnbilledTransactionCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id c in toplavelobject)
        {
            if ([c isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell=(YourCustomcell *) c;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps you :)

**Also make sure your custom cell is subclass of `UITableViewCell`**